# How to pass a tex formatted string as a parameter to a metapost macro?

Tags: labels, metapost

For example I want to pass the string `\huge$p_2f_1$`

To the macro

```
vardef macro(expr point, lab)=
    label(btex lab, point);
enddef;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `btex ... etex` tags convert the TeX expression between them into a picture, not a string.

You could use something like this

```
vardef macro(expr point, lab)=
    label(lab, point);
enddef;
```

and then

```
macro(origin, btex your TeX code etex);
```

Or, assuming you're using LuaLaTeX and `luamplib` with the option `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}`, then the text argument of `label` is indeed supposed to be a string and you can enter something like this when you use the macro above:

```
macro(origin, "your TeX code");
```